# Numpy: nansum for all bad slices returns 0

Tags: python, numpy

Quick question because I feel like this is not working as intended because:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.nansum([np.nan, np.nan]))
```

returns 0 instead of NaN...is this intentional? I am using Numpy v1.12.0 btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

Return the sum of array elements over a given axis **treating Not a Numbers (NaNs) as zero.**

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html

Comment: Oh god, and I thought I had looked at the documentation! :X I guess I should check my code now...

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, that is exactly what the [nansum function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html) does:

Return the sum of array elements over a given axis treating Not a Numbers (NaNs) as zero.